# cant scan and ping my ip from outside

Tags: nmap

when I scan my network using nmap it gives me something like this

```
#nmap -vv -Pn -sV -sT -p80 -oG - 116.135.*.*
# Ports scanned: TCP(1;80) UDP(0;) SCTP(0;) PROTOCOLS(0;)
Host: 116.135.*.* ()    Status: Up
Host: 116.135.*.* ()    Ports: 80/open/tcp//http//Allegro RomPager 4.07 UPnP|1.0 (ZyXEL ZyWALL 2)/
```

But When I scan the same ip from outside it give me / [also cant ping it from outside]

```
# nmap -vv -Pn -sV -sS -p80 -oG - 116.135.*.*
# Ports scanned: TCP(1;80) UDP(0;) SCTP(0;) PROTOCOLS(0;)
Host: 116.135.*.*  ()   Status: Up
Host: 116.135.*.*  ()   Ports: 80/filtered/tcp//http///
# Nmap done at Wed Nov 11 15:49:50 2015 -- 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.13 seconds
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I need to know why i get diffrent results

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you can scan from the inside indicates that your router/firewall allows the scans from the inside to its 'own' owned resource.

If you can't scan or ping it from the outside I'd look at your ICMP settings etc.

This sounds very much like a firewall/port filtering issue to me - I'd start in that end if I were you.

// Mike